# Get windows build number in Haskell

Tags: windows, haskell, version, build-numbers

How can I get windows build number in Haskell? I think I can use `readProcess` and `ver`, but maybe there are more clear methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Win32` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.8.3.0/docs/System-Win32-Info-Version.html) seems to allow to access the build number, within the IO monad. Untested.

```
import System.Win32.Info.Version -- from Win32 package

main :: IO ()
main = do
   osVersionInfo <- getVersionEx
   print (dwBuildNumber osVersionInfo)
```

Comment: Isn't it an overkill for such simple task?

Comment: @MalyutinEgor Overkill? Why do you think that? It couldn't be much simpler than that: importing a single library and using one library function to query OS information. Further, it's also way more efficient than spawning an external process to call `ver`, and parsing the output.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a native C function in WinAPI that returns Windows build number?

If yes, you can easily call it from Haskell using [ForeignFunctionInterface](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface) extension.